# Standard Response of a Login/Sign In API

Tags: api, rest

While making an Login/SignUp RESTful API, should the response contain any other user information e.g. User Profile, Permissions etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done this previously the Login returns a token for the new session and possibly the userid. Then I've had other services that I call with this token to get a list of permissions etc. You should make each resource do a single thing, which allows greater flexibility and reuse. Like everything though... this is my opinion on it but there is no right or wrong way to do it.

The REST principle is that when you POST a request to the server, it should respond with a status to indicate success or failure (i.e. 201 created) and a pointer to the new resource just created.

In my comments above the resource being created is the session and the token is the identifier of that resource.